# Distribute app with Developer ID with Hardened Runtime and 3rd party CLI-executable - Code sign Error

Tags: xcode, ffmpeg, executable, code-signing, notarize

**While I tried to distribute my app with Developer ID from Xcode Organizer, I got this error:**

> Hardened Runtime is not enabled.
>
> "ffmpeg" must be rebuilt with support for the Hardened Runtime. Enable the Hardened Runtime capability in the project editor, test your app, rebuild your archive, and upload again.

[image]

`Hardened Runtime` is enabled in `Project` > `Signing & Capabilites`.

My app has the [FFmpeg CLI tool](https://ffmpeg.org) in its Resources folder.

Since FFmpeg is a compiled binary, I have no option to enable `Hardened Runtime`.

How can I solve this and have my app properly code signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this codesign guide](https://lessons.livecode.com/m/4071/l/1122100-codesigning-and-notarizing-your-lc-standalone-for-distribution-outside-the-mac-appstore) I found how to code sign all included binaries (e.g. CLI tools like FFmpeg).

Add a new `Run Script Phase` in `Build Phases`:

```
codesign --force --options=runtime \
--sign "${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME}" \
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg"
```

You can use this this method for other locations/subpaths inside your app e.g. `/Contents/Frameworks/` etc. Just open your app package and watch the folder path.

If you have several binaries, repeat the codesign command for each binary path.

Comment: Also set `User script sandboxing` to `NO` (under **Build settings**) - I mentioning it that, so that I can remember it, the next time I come across your answer, looking for the exact same solution lol